# Django REST - @action decorator "Unresolved reference 'action'"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the @action decorator in my views.py but it's not being recognized. Is it deprecated or something?

[image]

```
class CategoryTargetGroupDelete(APIView):
    queryset = CategoryTargetGroup.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['delete'])
    def delete(self, request):
        cat_id = request.query_params['cat_id']
        queryset = CategoryTargetGroup.objects.filter(category=cat_id)
        queryset.delete()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have tried importing action..

[image]

DRF 3.7.1

Python 3.9

Comment: I think we can't use decorators like this in class view. Check alternative of @action in class view.

Comment: @sandeep What's the alternative of action in a class view?

Comment: The action decorator is meant for ViewSet methods. I don't think it will work with views subclassed from APIView. I can't explain why your IDE gives you that warning, though. The usage of `@action` in ViewSets is explained in the drf docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@action` decorator added to rest_framework in version [3.8.0](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#380). You can increase rest_framework version or use `@detail_route` or `@list_route` instead of `@action` decorator

more detail [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations)

Comment: Thank you, I have upgraded my DRF version. This leads me to a new problem: AttributeError: module 'django.db.migrations.serializer' has no attribute 'data' (I have created a new question about this, I can't link it here but help would be much appreciated.)

Answer (score 1):

Well without any additional infos like the drf version its kind of hard.
but do you get the action from here?

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
```

Comment: Cannot find reference 'action'.. I have added a screenshot of the error and my versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might had not imported actions.

Try

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
```

Comment: Cannot find reference 'action'.. I have added a screenshot of the error and my versions.